# Scala Spray Templated Custom Routing Directive

Tags: json, scala, generics, spray, shapeless

Okay so.... I have this:

```
  def convertPost  = extract {
    _.request.entity.asString.parseJson.convertTo[CustomClass]
  }

  private def myRoute: Route =
    (post & terminalPath("routeness")) {
      convertPost { req =>
        detach() {
           ThingHandler.getMyResults( req )
        }
      }
    }
```

but I want to template it, like this:

```
  def convertPost[T] = extract {
    _.request.entity.asString.parseJson.convertTo[T]
  }

  private def myRoute: Route =
    (post & terminalPath("routeness")) {
      convertPost[CustomClass] { req =>
        detach() {
           ThingHandler.getMyResults( req )
        }
      }
    }
```

But that doesn't work.  I am using [spray-json-shapeless](https://github.com/fommil/spray-json-shapeless).  My error is

```
Error:(28, 50) Cannot find JsonReader or JsonFormat type class for T
    _.request.entity.asString.parseJson.convertTo[T]
                                                 ^
```

when I try:

```
  def getStuff[T] = extract {
    _.request.entity.asInstanceOf[T] // .convertTo[T]
  }
```

it gives:

```
spray.http.HttpEntity$NonEmpty cannot be cast to com.stuff.CustomClass
```

Comment: Why don't you use `entity(as[CustomClass])`?

Comment: Some of my json has more than 22 elements and I can only get entity as to work with a json protocol class that uses jsonformat. I know work arounds but I feel like this should be ok if I just knew generics better.

Comment: What `entity(as[CustomClass])` does is to parse your JSON entity as CustomClass and it is exactly what `getStuff` wants to do. Implementation of JsonFormat is another issue, you can still implement custom JsonFormat.

Comment: With json format I have to break things into sub classes/objects and I'd rather not.  I have it written the other way.  I just think this is better - if I could figure it out.